# absolutely center CSS div with a caveat

Tags: html, css

I have a popup that's centered on my page using the following syntax:

```
position:absolute;
top: 50% !important;
left: 50% !important;
transform: translate(-50%,-38%); //well, slightly lower than center...
```

[image]
This works very well - unless the height of my popup is greater than the height of my current window.  It doesn't happen often, but when it does, I can scroll DOWN to see the additional content, but I cannot scroll UP any further than the top of the window to see what's above, like in this example:

[image]

I tried adding `padding-top:20px!important` but that did nothing.  I want to say `vertically center, but if the height of the div would cause the top of it to not be displayed, just affix the div to the top of the window instead`

What code would I add into this to achieve that?

## Edit

This is similar to another post on SO:

[How to center an element vertically in css in a scrollable container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31215600/how-to-center-an-element-vertically-in-css-in-a-scrollable-container)

I'm not looking to center the item with a flex container however.  Although this is a great post, and the flex logic works to center the item, I am looking to center UNLESS the height of the div is too great - then i want it to affix itself to the top of the window.

If I could place some sort of div above this popup div that has a height of 1px and force the popup div never to go higher than it, that would be fine as well.  I have a very specific reason for why I want the div at the TOP of the window when it's very long - I don't want it centered 100% of the time (which is what the other post does.)