# Center div vertically or affix to top of window if height is too great

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a popup that's centered on my page using the following syntax:

```
position:absolute;
top: 50% !important;
left: 50% !important;
transform: translate(-50%,-38%); //well, slightly lower than center...
```

[image]
This works very well - unless the height of my popup is greater than the height of my current window.  It doesn't happen often, but when it does, I can scroll DOWN to see the additional content, but I cannot scroll UP any further than the top of the window to see what's above, like in this example:

[image]

I want to say `vertically center, but if the height of the div would cause the top of it to not be displayed, just affix the div to the top of the window instead`

What code would I add into this to achieve that?

This is similar to another post on SO:

[How to center an element vertically in css in a scrollable container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31215600/how-to-center-an-element-vertically-in-css-in-a-scrollable-container)

I'm not looking to center the item with a flex container however.  I actually cannot use flex in this instance, because the div is a result of a javascript plugin and I can't add a separate parent div outside of this without a LOT of work.  I am looking to center UNLESS the height of the div is too great - then i want it to affix itself to the top of the window.

If I could place some sort of div above this popup div that has a height of 1px and force the popup div never to go higher than it, that would be fine as well.  I have a very specific reason for why I want the div at the TOP of the window when it's very long - I don't want it centered 100% of the time (which is what the other post does.)

I've also tried using a pseudo-element like so:

```
.popUpBody::before {
  content: " ";
  height:50px; //this needs to be dynamic based on the height of the parent
  width:100%px;
  display:block;    
}
```

as it moves the rest of the div down - but I'd need to find some way to use a dynamic height - it might be 300px, or it might be 5000px.  This also doesn't seem like a very good way to do this.

I could make it so the height of popup div is always centered by taking out the second `transform` variable: `transform: translate(-50%);` - and this would be a last resort, but I would really like for the div to affix to the top of the window when its height is larger than the window itself - if this is possible.

Javascript/Jquery is fine if I need to use that to add dynamics.

Comment: Is it possible to create a demo? It would be much easier to solve your Issue.

Comment: Or better provide a link to your site